# Can I use AspectJ to "wrap" a field with ThreadLocal?

Tags: java, thread-safety, aspectj

Let's say we have a class which looks like the following.

```
public class MyClass {

   @ThreadScoped    
   private Collection<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

   public void addWord(String word) {
        words.add(word);
   }

}
```

In runtime, we only have a single instance of this class, but it accepts calls from multiple threads.

I want the developer who writes the class to be able to ignore the fact that they're writing it for multi-thread access and just annotate the field as "thread scoped".

Is it possible to create an aspect which makes each calling thread have its own collection of words, as if the words field would have been a `ThreadLocal`? The collection should be tied to the thread even over multiple invocations of the method.

I have seen the `set` and `get` point cuts, but cannot figure out a way to make use of them that would not require me to set the field on the object, which would ruin the thread safety of the class.

Is there perhaps another way to do that which does not make use of aspects, such as with proxies or reflection?

Comment: Can you just tell why you cannot make it a ThreadLocal?

Comment: We don't want to force developers to use `ThreadLocal` in an attempt to keep the code as clean and "POJO like" as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is impossible using AspectJ in a generic way for several reasons:

- There is no generic way of cloning an object upon creation, not even for Collections. Then think about primitive types.
- Even if you do clone an object into a `ThreadLocal` in a specific `set()` pointcut, how do you redirect method calls upon the object to the clone?

Having said that, a way for you to go is to write a source code preprocessor doing some magic (wrapping the objects in question and method calls upon them). The preprocessor would weave its code into the sources before you would then normally compile them with *javac*.

Anyway, as thkala said I think the simplest solution is to teach your developers to actually use `ThreadLocal` by themselves or use tread-local wrappers provided by your API (which you would have to implement).

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be a couple of potentially conflicting decisions in your design:

- You only have a single instance of `MyClass`.
- You want each thread to view its own version of the `words` field.

It seems to me that using AspectJ for this purpose might be overkill. I suppose that thread-specific access could be considered a cross-cutting concern, but I am not sure that AOP is the way to deal with this. I would first consider a redesign of the pure Java code, before trying AspectJ.

Quite honestly, I believe that the simplest way to achieve the second effect would be for each thread to have its own instance of `MyClass`. You could even use a `ThreadLocal` to provide access to the proper `MyClass` instance if explicitly passing it to each thread is not an option.

If you have fields in `MyClass` that are shared by more than one thread, then you might want to consider refactoring `MyClass` to break it up into two classes. That would separate the thread-specific from the shared fields, allowing you to treat each case differently.

**EDIT:**

I thought about your comments a bit and it seems to me that you are trying to use AOP to essentially hide the implementation of the field from your developers. The problem of separating the programming interface from the actual implementation has been mostly solved in Object-Oriented programming, without resolving to AOP.

In your case the way to go would be to use an abstract superclass for `MyClass` to hold a *private* declaration for that field and then use a couple of getter and setter methods to let `MyClass` work with it. That way you can change the actual implementation without affecting anything else.

```
public abstract AbstractMyClass {
    private ... words = ...;

    protected Collection<String> getWords() {
        ...
    }
}

public Myclass extends AbstractMyClass {
   public void addWord(String word) {
        this.getWords().add(word);
   }
}
```

Comment: In the actual design, there will not be a single `MyClass` but tens or potentially even hundreds different classes. It is in an OSGi environment, where we're not in charge of creating the objects. Therefore, we cannot create a separate instance of `MyClass` for each thread.

Comment: I like your idea of using pure OOP to solve the problem. The thing we want to avoid in this case is forcing developers to create not only one class, but two (the abstract one as well).